# Why is my table formula taking very long to calculate?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

It has been my experience that whenever I try to put formulas in a table column (iterating over cells in a table column), it takes a long time.
In the below code I am trying to do `Iferror(vlookup)` combination, it's taking very long. I can't write a direct formula with Vlookup here as I am referring a table on another workbook. I have already used

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

but no help.

**Sample code**

```
For Each r In Table.ListColumns(Column_name).DataBodyRange
    Set Z = Workbooks(workbookname).Worksheets(worksheetname).ListObjects(Table).ListColumns(Column_name).Range.Find(Valuefind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not Z Is Nothing Then
        r.Offset(0, -1) = Z
    Else
        r.Offset(0, -1) = r
    End If

Next r
```

Comment: Well using `find` in a loop is in deed very time consuming. That will probably not change until you change your approach completely. You should better provide a [mcve] including example data and telling us what you actually want to do. Maybe you are already up the wrong tree. How many iterations has your loop round about?

Comment: 200000 multiplied by 5 columns :(

Comment: Why is`Set Z =...` in the loop as it doesn't change?

Comment: That means 1 million runs of `find` + 1 million cell read/write actions. What do you expect? Of course this takes a long time. Please read my first comment again and provide much more information.

Comment: Set Z = the value found by the find function corresponding to each r, actually r should be the "valuefind" in the expression...my wrong way of simplifying things

Comment: your question is: `Why is my table formula taking very long to calculate?` however the post does not shows any formula. As to why *"whatever you are trying to do"* is taking too long, @Peh already answered it. If you really want some help in achieving your goal, then we need to know what is that  *"whatever you are trying to do"*, I suggest that you please follow the advice received and update your post, so we can help you. Help yourself to get help!…